# How to exclude LAN traffic from IPSEC policy

Tags: linux-networking, ipsec, mikrotik, rfc

I am trying to replace a Firewall/VPN appliance (Snapgear SG300) with another (Mikrotik RB951G-2HnD).  My current router works, but, for the new mikrotik router, when I add the phase 2 tunnel, I can no longer access the router.

I suspect the problem is caused by my LAN being a subset of what is tunneled to my office.

If I have a phase 2 tunnel of 10.0.0.0/8 and my local LAN is 10.1.1.0/24 (and the router is 10.1.1.1), how do I set this up?

I did try to create a policy that excluded 10.1.1.0/24 --> 10.1.1.0/24 pass but either I did it wrong or it wasn't the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to avoid routing inconsistencies will be to configure a tunnel that does not overlap with your LAN segment.

Take a look at the [RouterOS's packet flow](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Packet_Flow) diagrams. should your tunnel's CIDR be that wide, all of the packets will reach the IPsec Encryption step, and once there, [IPsec policies](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/IPsec#Policy) won't provide that "ignore IPsec" behavior you intend to configure; packets may not be encrypted (IPsec action=none), but IPsec protocol headers will be added and IP address may be mangled according to the SAs.